# How can I get Windows 7 Explorer lists to use the same compact line spacing as Windows XP's?

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer

Here's compact XP on the left and wasteful 7 on the right:

[image]

How do I get 7's Explorer lists to be as compact as XPs?

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tested it, but this thread seems to solve the issue.  See the last post, as there is a screenshot and the user seems to summarize the steps:

[Windows 7 - possible to change list item height/spacing?](http://www.sevenforums.com/customization/45276-possible-change-list-item-height-spacing-6.html)